# Use knife commands from ruby without bash

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, knife

I'm trying to remove the following bash command from my ruby script:

```
nodes = "knife search 'chef_environment:#{env} AND recipe:#{microservice}' -i 2>&1 | tail -n 2"
node = %x[ #{nodes} ].split 
node.each do |n|
  puts n
end
```

And replace it with something like this:

```
node = Chef::Knife.search("chef_environment:#{env} AND recipe:#{microservice}").split
```

Is this possible? Is there any documentation regarding Chef::knife library in ruby and how to use it?

Answer (score 0):

To access a chef server, you could try to use the [ridley](https://github.com/berkshelf/ridley) gem, which is also used by Berkshelf and thus generally up-to-date.

A usage example could be:

```
ridley = Ridley.from_chef_config('/path/to/knife.rb')
ridley.search(:node, "chef_environment:#{env} AND recipe:#{microservice}")
```

See the documentation of the gem for a more detailed description of its options.

Comment: is failing reading server certificate  ERROR -- : Actor crashed!, obviously knife search is working.   Ridley::Errors::ClientError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B

Comment: your server certificate is not trusted.

Comment: Ensure that knife (and by extension ridley) trust your chef server's SSL certificate. Please follow https://docs.chef.io/knife_ssl_check.html for that.

Comment: I would generally recommend chef-api over ridley. Ridley is great if you need to micro-optimize performance but it means (usually) dealing with Celluloid which is overkill for a simple script.

Comment: @coderanger what is the command/documentations for knife serach command with Chef API?